# Find used simulink parameters

Tags: parameters, simulink, inlining

I'm searching for a possibility to get a list of all used parameters within a subsystem.
It's the same list, simulink coders shows when starting s-Function build of a subsystem.
[image: example with f14-demo-model]

Parameters can exists within nearly every block (gain, lookup-table, staturation, constant...) and also within embedded stateflow.

My first idea is to start a "find_system" to get all gain-blocks and then check their parameters step by step. But this seems to be complicated, because I've to check every single block type with different interesting parameters (gain=gain; lookup-table: table-data, breakpoint-data...). I also don't know how to find parameters within stateflow.

Is there a simpler approch to get all used parameters?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're asking for [Simulink.findvars](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/simulink.findvars.html).